# HTML email has gap on right on mobile IOS 8

Tags: email, ios8, html-email, padding, tablerow

I'm having an issue with this HTML email having a gap on the right side on mobile (IOS 8). This image shows the gap on the right when tested for mobile, iPhone IOS 8.

[image]

I've tried/double-checked many things: min-width is 100%, responsive is set to 100% width as well, and I've searched here. The images aren't too wide; they're 600px in width. I tried specifying body width, and I have td align="center". Any additional ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
<!-- CSS Reset -->
<style>

    /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
    /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
    table,
    td {
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
    }

    /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
    table {
        border-spacing: 0 !important;
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
        table-layout: fixed !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    table table table {
        table-layout: auto;
    }

    /* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/issues/89  */
    /* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */
    /* Thanks to Eric Lepetit @ericlepetitsf) for help troubleshooting */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) { /* iPhone 6 and 6+ */
        .email-container {
            min-width: 375px !important;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {  /* Force iOS Mail to render the email at full width */
        body {width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important; min-width:100vw !important;}
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .hero-img {
            height:auto !important;
            max-width:600px !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
</style>

<!-- Progressive Enhancements -->

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style>
li {
text-indent: -1em; /* Normalise space between bullets and text */
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body padding="0" width="100%" min-width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; mso-line-
height-rule: exactly;">
<center style="width: 100%; min-width: 100%; background: #ffffff; text-
align: center; display: inline-block;">
<div class="email-container" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0px 
auto;"><!--[if mso]>
        <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" 
cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <![endif]--><!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px;" 
width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="word-wrap:normal;" 
class=""><a href="#"><img alt="" aria-hidden="true" border="0" 
height="290" src="#" title="" valign="middle"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- Email Header : END --><!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="text-align: center; max-
width: 600px;" width="100%">
<tbody><!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="stack-column-center" style="display: 
block; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; 
line-height: 16px; word-wrap:normal; color:#4e4e4e; text-align: left; 
padding: 0px 72px 0px 72px;"><br>
        Hello,<br>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum.<br>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum.<br>
        <br>
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">To lorem ipsum, please click 
below:</span><br>
        &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- Button : Begin -->
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="margin: auto; text-align: 
center; max-width: 600px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="button-td" pardot-data="link-
underline:none !important;" style="word-wrap:normal; background: 
#ffb81c; text-align: center; text-decoration: none !important;"><a 
class="button-a" href="#" style="background: rgb(255, 184, 28); border: 
15px solid rgb(255, 184, 28); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-
serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; display: block; text-
decoration: none !important;"><span class="button-link" 
style="color:#000000; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none !important;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BUTTON&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- Button : END -->

<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px; text-align: center;" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="stack-column-center" style="word-wrap:normal; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4em; color: #4e4e4e; text-align: left; padding: 0px 72px 0px 72px;" width="100%"><br>
        List ipsum:<br>
        <ul style="padding: 0px; Margin: 0px 0px 0px 40px;">
            <li style="Margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">Lorem</li>
            <li style="Margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum.<br>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum.<br></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- Infographic: Begin -->
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px; text-align: center;" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="stack-column-center" style="word-wrap:normal; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4em; color: #4e4e4e; text-align: left; padding: 0px 72px 0px 72px;" width="100%"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #002b48;">To lorem ipsum, you will need:</span><br>
        <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0px; Margin: 0px 0px 0px 40px;">
            <li style="Margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;">1. Lorem</li>
            <li style="Margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;">2. Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- Email Footer : Begin -->
<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px; text-align: center;" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="word-wrap:normal;" class=""><img alt="" aria-hidden="true" border="0" height="305" src="#" title="" valign="middle"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px; text-align: center;" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" height="32" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" class="x-gmail-data-detectors" style="word-wrap:normal; vertical-align: middle; border-spacing: 0px; font-size: 8px; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 11px; text-align: center; color: #2e2e2e;" valign="middle"><a href="%%view_online%%"><webversion style="color:#2e2e2e; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold;">View as a Web Page</webversion></a><br>
        <br>
        <a href="%%unsubscribe%%" style="display: block; color:#2e2e2e; word-wrap:normal; text-decoration:underline; text-transform: uppercase;">Click here to unsubscribe</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" height="32" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;" valign="middle" class="">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- Email Footer : END --><!--[if mso]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]--></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an example with the image and the text we could look at? I've run across a similar problem with my own emails, but I can't determine the fix quite yet.

Comment: You have the first table as 600 width. Try changing it with max-width 600 and width 100%, see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, Syfer. I did as you both suggested and it worked. I was having an issue with the header text being cropped at the top/cut off on top, as well, and I think this had to do with the images too, but I will have to recreate and test.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for using [Cerberus](https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/)! (I'm the primary author and maintainer. I noticed this is an older version. It should still work, but please know it's been updated significantly :)

Regarding your problem at hand, it seems the issue is the images. There's a style defined for the images in the `<head>`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .hero-img {
        height:auto !important;
        max-width:600px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

But this class isn't defined in the images:

```
<img alt="" aria-hidden="true" border="0" height="290" src="#" title="" valign="middle">
```

I'm not sure how width these images are natively, but they won't shrink down as-is. On small screens, they'll stay at their native width, even if it breaks the rest of the email :(

---

**Option 1:** Adding the class to these images will make the images responsive in email clients that support media queries (which, these days, is most):

```
<img alt="" aria-hidden="true" border="0" width="600" height="" src="#" title="" valign="middle" class="hero-img">
```

**Option 2:** editing the `height` and `width` attributes and adding a few inline CSS properties makes the images responsive by default:

```
<img alt="" aria-hidden="true" border="0" height="290" src="#" title="" valign="middle" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;">
```

(No media queries required!)

Comment: Option 2 worked, thanks! Natively the images were 600px wide. I was specifying an incorrect height for the first image though after the client had us add to its length (I had forgotten to account for the new height). I removed the last two media queries.